# My Mac has recently been freezing several times a day and then eventually having to restart, unsure how to understand the error message or how to fix

Tags: macos, catalina, performance

My computer keeps restarting and I am unsure how to fix it, or if I will need to get a new Mac. I get this error report every time:

> panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801fed1b92):  initproc exited -- exit
>   reason namespace 2 subcode 0xa description: none
>
> uuid info:  0x1142ea000   uuid =  
>   0x1046da000   uuid = <5daa6d02-cc15-36b3-816c-d88fcf7c8e8a>
>
> Thread 2 crashed
>
> RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x00007fc1e603f000, RCX:
>   0x0100000000000000, RDX: 0x0040000000000000 RSP: 0x00007000079637e0,
>   RBP: 0x0000700007963830, RSI: 0x00007fc1e603f000, RDI:
>   0x00007fc1e503b000 R8:  0x0000000000008001, R9:  0x00007fc1e6170800,
>   R10: 0x00007fc1e6170800, R11: 0x00007fc1e6000000 R12:
>   0x00007fc1e503b3f8, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x00007fc1e503b000,
>   R15: 0x0000000000000003 RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP:
>   0x0000000104700868, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023
>
> Thread 0: 0xffffff8032e29a40  0x00007fff64ef3226  0x00007fff64d66376
>     0x0000000000000000
>
> Thread 1: 0xffffff8037c7ea40  0x00007fff64f0fdc2  0x00007fff64d586c0
>     0x00007fff64d683c4  0x00007fff64d5b980  0x00007fff64d5c452
>     0x00007fff64d65a9e  0x00007fff64faf71b  0x00007fff64faf57b
>     0x0000000000000000
>
> Thread 2: 0xffffff8037f7e000  0x0000000104700868  0x00007fff64d5650e
>     0x00007fff64d586c0  0x00007fff64d683c4  0x00007fff64d5b980
>     0x00007fff64d5c452  0x00007fff64d65a9e  0x00007fff64faf71b
>     0x00007fff64faf57b  0x0000000000000000
>
> Thread 3: 0xffffff8039956520  0x00007fff64faf56c
>
> Thread 4: 0xffffff8032898a40  0x00007fff64faf56c
>
> Mac OS version: 19B88
>
> Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT
>   2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID:
>   7503CD47-851F-321E-8747-50DB4299165F System model name: MacBookPro11,2
>   (Mac-3CBD00234E554E41) Root disk errors: "Could not recover SATA HDD
>   after 5 attempts. Terminating." System shutdown begun: NO Panic diags
>   file available: YES (0x0)

Any advice would really help, thanks.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I see your running macOS Catalina on a 2013 MBP, but can you advise the specs? Also, how long have you been experiencing this problem for? Did it coincide with something else (e.g. new software, new hardware, etc)? But, as an initial observation, it looks to me like your internal hard drive is failing.